# isSelected() does not recognize JRadioButton and JCheckBox are selected

Tags: java, jpanel, jradiobutton

I'm new here, and this is my very first post.

I have a very specific need to code this very trivial application only invoking the isSelected() method to check whether or not a JRadioButton or JCheckBox have been selected. This means I do not want to loop through a ButtonGroup and invoke its getSelection() method.

My code is also identical to the one from a textbook authored by Tony Gaddis, which I am currently learning from: *Starting Out With Java*, *From Control Structures through Objects*. *4th Edition*.

This is a **logical problem**, as the application compiles and runs without error.

Here's what's going on:

I have four classes: BagelsPanel, CoffeePanel, ToppingsPanel and the GUI class, BagelApp - all of which extend JPanel **except** the BagelApp class which extends a JFrame.

The purpose of the app is to let a user make coffee, bagel and toppings selections and return the total price of all their selections. The problem is it keeps returning $0.00.

My suspicion is, for some reason, isSelected() isn't recognizing something is selected.

I will post the BagelsPanel and the GUI class code that involves these problems below:

```
public double calcBagel() {

    double total = 0.00;

    if(button1.isSelected())
        total = PLAIN;
    else if(button2.isSelected()) 
        total = WHOLE_WHEAT;
    else if(button3.isSelected()) 
        total = CINNA_RAISON;
    else if(button4.isSelected()) 
        total = EVERYTHING;

    return total;
}
```

The above is the calcBagel() method in the BagelsPanel class that's invoking the isSelected() method to check which JRadioButton is selected, then **assigning** its price to total. Below is the GUI class:

```
public void buildPanel() {

    panel = new JPanel();
    calc = new JButton("Calculate");
    calc.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    panel.add(calc);
}
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        double subtotal = 0.0;
        double total = 0.0;
        bagels = new BagelPanel();
        coffee = new CoffeePanel();
        toppings = new ToppingsPanel();

        subtotal = bagels.calcBagel() + coffee.calcCoffee() +
                    toppings.calcToppings();
        double tax = subtotal * TAX;
        total = subtotal + tax;

        DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your total is: " 
                    + dollar.format(total));    
    }
}
```

Here's some insight: if I change the double variable total, in the calcBagel() method inside the BagelsPanel class to 1.0, and then run the application and click on the JRadioButton "Calculate," it accurately props up a JOptionPane telling me my total is $1.06 (the final double variable TAX is set at 0.06).

I'd really appreciate any help I can get. I'm still a beginner in Java and don't quite understand why my logic is incorrect. I'm embarrassed this might be extremely trivial but I've checked the book and the code is identical. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to show us the minimum amount of code that will reproduce the problem: http://sscce.org. With the right code example you won't need so much explanation.

Comment: People reading these code fragments don't know the scope of the variables, or how the buttons are declared, or why you suspect isSelected(), etc.  You have a lot of explanation, but not enough information.  I will tell you that one of the hard things to learn about debugging is the conviction that you have made a mistake and should therefore look for it in your code, instead of thinking it must be a mistake somewhere else (like isSelected()).  Try putting a JButton on your UI and having its action routine test isSelected() and System.out.println() a message about it.

Comment: @SkipHead - Thanks for the link. I really was under the impression I was doing just that but I guess there's more of a science to it. I'll definitely make sure I use this the next time I post.

Comment: @rcook - Thanks for the advice. I did both prior to posting here but still got the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is right here, in your `actionPerformed` method:

```
    double total = 0.0;
    bagels = new BagelPanel();
    coffee = new CoffeePanel();
    toppings = new ToppingsPanel();
```

Instead of invoking the methods `calcBagel(), calcCoffee(), calcToppings()` on the panels that are displayed, you are creating new panels out of nowhere and invoking "calc-methods" on them. Of course they are different objects of the one the user is manipulating in the UI. You should keep a reference to the panels you originally added to your GUI and invoke "calc-methods" on those, not on newly created objects.

P.S: Your code is really mixing model and views.

Comment: Thank you! You were absolutely correct! Not only did I have instances of those 3 classes as private instance variables of the BagelApp class, I created brand new ones out of nowhere just as you pointed out. Deleting those 3 statements solved the problem! I would vote you up, but I'm unable to until I get a higher reputation score. Thank you, again.

Answer (score 1):

Without a real [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org), this is a little hard to answer, but here's what I would do: Using my favorite IDE ([Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) in my case), I would set a breakpoint at the start of `calcBagel()` and step through the code line-by-line with the debugger to make sure the variables are set.

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
public double calcBagel() {
    System.out.println("In calcBagel()");
    double total = 0.00;

    if(button1.isSelected()) {
        System.out.println("button1 is selected! Setting total to " + PLAIN);
        total = PLAIN;
    }
    else if(button2.isSelected())  {
        System.out.println("button2 is selected! Setting total to " + WHOLE_WHEAT);
        total = WHOLE_WHEAT;
    }
    else if(button3.isSelected())  {
        System.out.println("button3 is selected! Setting total to " + CINNA_RAISON);
        total = CINNA_RAISON;
    }
    else if(button4.isSelected())  {
        System.out.println("button4 is selected! Setting total to " + EVERYTHING);
        total = EVERYTHING;
    } else {
        System.out.println("No buttons were selected!");
    }
    System.out.println("total = " + total);
    return total;
}
```

This would be a good way to figure out what's going on with your method as well. Your problem could also very easily not be in this method at all. But this would be a way to find that out.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried that prior to posting here but it would just print out 0.00 in the console. It's all solved now, though. Thanks for your input, however!